# Is there a way to check if a next event includes a term in the title?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have made a script that updates events title after an user submits a form, based on this condition:

```
for(var j=0; j<events.length;j++){
        var ev = events[j];
        if(!ev.getTitle().includes("Returned"){ ...
```

I want the script to check if there is one or many events that include the term "Returned", but only among the next events.

For example, the condition should be false if an event title does not include "Returned" AND none of the next events titles include "Returned".

Is that possible? I tried with creating a variable `evnext = events[j+1]` but of course I get an error once it gets to the last event.

Thank you for your help, I feel it is very doable but my understanding of loops is sadly too low ...

**Edit: details on my goal**

Actually my script sends an email to all people who borrowed an equipment but did not confirm they returned it.

The problem now is that I would like to send an email to these people EXCEPT IF someone else returned it afterwards.

It would indeed mean that even the first borrower did not confirm he returned it, the fact that someone who took it next and marked it as returns proves that the first person actually returned the equipment.

Otherwise it would not have been possible for the next guy to return it.

Comment: how does an event look like in your array?

Comment: Stopping looking them when i > events.length - 2

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script:

```
function listEvents()
{
  let calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar ID"); // Change the calendar ID
  var today = new Date();
  for(let i=1; i<=30; i++) // 30 days limit
  {
    var events = calendar.getEventsForDay(today, {search: 'Returned'});
    if(events.length != 0)
    {
      MailApp.sendEmail("email@domain.com","Subject","Body");
    }
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
  }
}
```

In this example the script takes the current date and starts checking day by day of a specific calendar for the upcoming 30 days if an event has the word "Returned" on its title and returns False if not.

Let me know if this helps. I can also modify the script if needed. You  can modify the 30 days limit, and the initial date depending on your needs. Do not forget to change the calendar ID to the one you are currently using to save the events.

References:

- [getEventsForDay(date, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#geteventsfordaydate,-options)

Comment: Hi Fernando, thanks for your answer. 
Actually my script sends an email to all people who borrowed an equipment but did not confirm they returned it. 
The problem now is that I would like to send an email to these people EXCEPT IF someone else returned it afterwards (it would mean that even the first borrower did not confirm he returned it, the fact that someone who took it next and marked it as returns proves that the first person actually returned the equipment. Otherwise it would not have been possible for the next guy to return it).

Comment: @user10879705 Are you using anything specific like an ID or something to identify the events from a specific item within the calendar events? I am asking because that way we could improve the search by only using that specific ID and the keyword "Returned" to find if it was returned in upcoming events or not.

Comment: At the moment I don't use any specific ID, but since these events are created via a script, I think I could do this. But would that really solve my issue? I mean, I can retrieve the events with "Returned" in the title quite easily already.

Comment: @user10879705 I updated the code with the condition that if an upcoming event with the "Returned" word in the subject exists, then it sends an email, otherwise it will not do anything. Let me know if that helps or if there is anything that you would like to change. If you already have a working script I would also suggest adding it to the question so that we can see what you are doing and try to adapt our answers based on what you currently have.

Comment: My script already works like that. But now instead of sending an email to all guests of events that include "Returned", I want to send an email to all guests of such events EXCEPT IF there is an event next to it which include "Returned" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for(var j=0; j<events.length;j++){
        var ev = events[j];
        if(j < events.length - 1) {
          if(ev.getTitle().include("Returned") && events[j+1].include("Returned")) {}
        } else {
          if(!ev.getTitle().includes("Returned") {}
        }
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, in this script, where should I use the actions `...` to be performed (just to be sure)?

Comment: Where would you guess?

Comment: I would guess here: `if(ev.getTitle().include("Returned") && events[j+1].include("Returned")) {...}` but the first part would then be wrong, since the event[j] should not include Returned.

Comment: And also, if I am not  wrong, this script only checks the next event right? Or does it also check all next events?